# Change PictureBox height dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling, picturebox

I am having a RichTextBox. On top of it, I draw number of pictureboxes. Pictureboxes donot contain any image, but setting background color to black. Initially, I set the height of each picturebox to be same as the height of richtextbox. But when I resize the richtextbox, I want to change the height of the pictureboxes as well.

I did this by listening to the Resize event handler of the richtextbox, there I get the current height of the richtextbox and change the height of picturebox accordingly. But the problem is that, I can see that the pictureboxes are getting larger but the latter part's background color is not set as black, but white. I try by invalidating & updating both richtextbox and pictureboxes, but nothing happens. Any ideas???

Resize code snippet:

```
void tbx_resize(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    var height = ((RichTextBox)sender).Height;
    foreach(PictureBox pic in ((RichTextBox)sender).Controls)
    {
       pic.Height = height;
       pic.Invalidate();
    }
    ((RichTextBox)sender).Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense.  A RichTextBox doesn't have a collection of PictureBox controls.  Post code that actually compiles.

Comment: You are right, i edited the post, but even so my requirement won't fulfilled...

Answer (score 3):

I have did this stuff like this..
**try this:**

```
void tbx_resize(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{     
    int height = ((RichTextBox)sender).Height;
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
       if (c is PictureBox)
       {
          c.Height = height;
       }
    } 
}
```

Comment: So could your mark the question as answered if it's answered? Thanks!

Comment: Ya, there was a compile time error there, which you have corrected in your answer, but even you correct the compile errors, the problem is still there, which i mentioned in my question